# balls and bins expectation of 2 variables?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, balls-in-bins

If I have 2 balls and 8 bins and I define the following indicator variable: $X_i = 1$ if bucket $X_i$ is empty and 0 otherwise. I'm trying to find the following quantity: $E[X_1X_2]$ How would I go about doing this since the two indicator variables are not independent.

I understand that $E[X_1 X_2] = Pr[X_1 = 1, \ X_2 = 1]$ but I'm struggling quite a lot calculating that probability. I've reached the following:

$Pr[X_1 = 1 \cap \ X_2 = 1] = Pr[X=1] + Pr[X=2] - Pr[X_1 = 1 \cup \ X_2 = 1]$

Where $Pr[X=1] = Pr[X=2] = \frac{7.6}{8^3}$ and I'm struggling to calculate the final quantity. Is this the correct approach, or is there a much simpler way?

Comment: You try yo write formulas. First step should be to write sentences, with english words, explaining the objective : $X_1X_2 =1$ when both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $1$, so when both bin n°1 and bin n°2 are empty. So the question is : what is the probability that both bin n°1 and bin n°2 are empty.  Or, in other words, what is the probability that the first ball is one of the remaining bins, ant the second ball is also in one of the remaining bins.  Now, we can start writing formulas. Another bigger problem, you write formulas like Pr[X=2], and you don't explain what Pr[X=2] is.

Answer (score 1):

If the placement of each ball is independent and uniformly at random among all $8$ bins, then the outcome $X_1 X_2 = 1$ means both bins $1$ and $2$ are empty.  This occurs with probability $(6/8)^2$.

If multiple balls are not permitted to be placed in the same bin, but again the placement is uniformly at random among all empty bins--that is to say, any pair of bins is equally likely to be selected for the two balls--then the probability that both bins $1$ and $2$ are empty is simply $\binom{6}{2}/\binom{8}{2}$.

Comment: Did you just multiply the two events together? Isn't this assuming that they're indepdenent? Do you mind explaining a bit further how you got the first answer?

Comment: @skidjoe $X_1,X_2$ are both 1 when both balls are placed in one of 6 bins (bins 3-8).  Since each ball is placed in one of the 6 bins with probability 6/8, and the placement of each ball is independent of the other, multiply and get $6/8\times 6/8$. Note this doesn't assume $X_1=1$ and $X_2=1$ are independent (those indicators concern the state of the bins).